# save whole web page with Ruby selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

how can i get whole web page (not just html) with Ruby selenium-webdriver? i tried this but this code just get html file , not img and css files or another.

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
driver.get(URL_of_page_to_save)
file = File.new(filename, "w")
file.puts(driver.page_source)
file.close
```

Comment: i need save page just like that , when i right click on chrome or Firefox and click on save as or Ctrl+S button. on this way all of the CSS , img , script and ... files of page , save into a folder (directory) away the html file. so when i run html , html , called self elements from this folder.

Comment: `Selenium` is not built for it. You can try use `Selenium` to choose the option from the right click menu using `Actions` or send keys `Ctrl+S` and use tool like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to interact with the dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not the complete tool for this, you're on the right track though.

Check out [Nokogiri](https://www.rubyguides.com/2012/01/parsing-html-in-ruby/). It should allow you to parse the HTML of the document to separately download the associated files that you need.